min_date и max_date не учитываются при поиске Messages_Search C# WTelegramClient
Я пытаюсь получить кол-во сообщений, отправленных в определенный промежуток времени используя метод Messages_Search():
var search = await TgClient.Messages_Search(id, string.Empty, null, new DateTime(2023, 08, 31), new DateTime(2024,08,01,23,59,59));

Но по какой-то причине происходит поиск за всё время, игнорируя параметры промежутка времени.
Использую библиотеку WTelegramClient

А где вы его вообще брали, в каком репозитории? В том что я нагуглил, вообще не удаётся найти такой метод с такими параметрами. И вообще эта штука очень плохо гуглится. Укажите источник библиотеки, которую вы используете.

@CrazyElf Репозиторий библиотеки: https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient
